# Check if number is in a number list

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

I am new to programming and I am trying to figure out how to create a list of numbers like so (5, 10, 15, 20, 25, all the way to 500) then be able to check if a player score is equal to any of these numbers.

My code so far is this.. It works, but only if the score is 5.

```
private void drawPower() {

    if (myWorld.getScore() == 5) {
        batcher.draw(Power, pipe3.getX(), pipe3.getY() + pipe3.getHeight()
                + 30, 20, -14);

    }

}
```

I need to know what needs to be done so instead of

```
if (myWorld.getScore() == 5) {
```

it would be

```
if (myWorld.getScore() == "any number in the list") {
```

Comment: Are the numbers always a multiple of a common number like 5?

Comment: collection.contains ? (a set would be appropriate)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wouldn't use an array of multiples of 5 from 5 to 100.

I would just check if it's a multiple of 5 and if it's between `5` and `500`.

```
int score = myWorld.getScore();
if (score >= 5 && score <= 500 && score % 5 == 0) {
```

Comment: You really saw the forest through the trees on that one.

Comment: +1 However I think `score % 5 == 0` should be first as its most likely to be false (lazy evaluation)

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked! I couldn't use the "int score = myWorld.getScore(); for some reason it threw exceptions and crashed the game. I just manually entered the myWorldGetScore() 3 times and it worked

Answer (score 4):

@rgettman's answer is definitely the best way. However to answer the question more generally (as it may come up again):

```
if(Arrays.asList(5, 10, 15, 20).contains(myWorld.getScore()))
```

However, if the numbers have any sort of pattern to them, a solution like rgettman's is definitely better. This is if the numbers are more or less arbitrary.

Comment: You could use a binary search since the numbers are ordered in the original collection. That would run in `O(logn)` instead of `O(n)`

Comment: @ZouZou is there a builtin for binary search? Sometimes simplicity in writing is more valuable than runtime. But yes, binary search is definitely faster.

Comment: `Collections.binarySearch`

Comment: @ZouZou ah cool. I'll update the answer later. I have to leave now.

Answer (score 0):

Since the array contains all the numbers from 5 up to 500 (with a step of 5) then:

```
public hasScore(int score) {  
   int position = (score/5) - 1;  
   return arrray[position] == score;  
}
```

I.e. the score should be in position (i/5) - 1 (since 5 in index 0, 10 in index 1) and so on.
So check if the score is indeed in the expected location it should be